# Direct input of Bias and gain value?

Tags: envi, landsat-8

I have facing a problem on arranging the SAM Classification on ENVI. I applied the Landsat 8 and want to classify the area using SAM on my private libraly, thus the system notice that for band 9 to 11 the bias and gain were lost. I tried to input them but do not know where to do and the system still define that they were still missing.

What can i do for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the gain and offset of your data from [ENVI header](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ENVIHeaderFiles.html) as there is a section to write a gain and offset. But before doing that, make sure to create a back up of your data and use the copied data to change the header of your files. However, I am not sure what values your need to enter because this information comes with the Landsat 8 data that you download.

If the gain and offset are missing, it is better to contact USGS and ask for clarification on why they are missing.